# Emacs, AUC Tex and Tex Live problem on Mac OS

Tags: emacs, auctex

I have (apparently) correctly installed MacTex 2010 and I am able to use it from the terminal and with Texmate.

But when I try to compile a Latex file using emacs in the AUC Tex mode it have an error.

Apparently the path to pdflatex is unknown although I added `/usr/texbin` in my `.bash_profile` file.

I tried to add this path to `/etc/paths` and to `/etc/bash_profile` but it is not working... Also, when I launch a bash terminal under emacs (with `M-x term`) I also have a very incomplete path.

How should I do to make this work ?

Comment: Try [this solution](http://superuser.com/questions/171681/installing-auctex-1-86-over-emacs-app-in-os-x/172596#172596) to a previous similar SU question. Specifically, edit/create a file `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`.

Comment: That's exactly what is was looking for. I didn't know about the difference between GUI and terminal app for environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using the `environment.plist` solution above (did it a few years ago, haven't reinstalled my computer in a while), but couldn't make it work at some point. So I simply inserted the missing paths into emacs, like this:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:" (getenv "PATH")))
(setq exec-path (append '("/opt/local/bin" "/opt/local/sbin") exec-path))
```

In this case, I'm adding the paths to the Macports binaries. Probably not the most beautiful solution, but at least it works :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the actual error and apparently I am too low level to ask you by a comment, so I'll make a wild guess.

With the auctex mode loaded, try C-cC-tC-p. This will change the settings to create a pdf.

Comment: Thanks, but I really think I have a problem with the path, so it does not change the problem.