# complete shell in emacs on OS X

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm using [carbon emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/) on mac OS X (snow leopard). I can use M-x shell or M-x eshell but these shells don't contain non-default commands, such as 'ack' that I added with MacPort. Is there some way to get a complete shell configuration in my emacs?

I bet it's possible since this works on Aquamacs. However I prefer carbon emacs for personal reasons.

Comment: When you say that you added non-default commands, do you mean in your .bash_profile or .profile, or some other method? I'd also be interested in hearing why you prefer carbon emacs, if you don't mind sharing.

Comment: @Larry : I prefer carbon emacs because it feels more neutral than aquamacs. With aquamacs you start with a bunch of stuff I don't really want. carbon emacs starts with the basic and I can add what I want the way I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You should also take a look at this thread here at SU.](https://superuser.com/questions/212068/emacs-auc-tex-and-tex-live-problem-on-mac-os/212672#212672)

Comment: Yes this thread fixed all possible problems I had with my PATH and shell.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add the path to your MacPort binaries to your `PATH`. Add this at the end of your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```